# SSL: Insecure Content IE

Tags: security, internet-explorer, ssl

I'm currently building a website for our business, where the website is expected to work perfectly, even back to the earlier IEs down to 7.

URL - https://secure.marietta.at

The page does not load any insecure content in Chrome, but I can see in IE that there is a GET param sent to http://marietta.at, which in turn redirects to http://en.marietta.at

I have no idea where I've specified this. I tried deleting scripts, checking the css, debugging with IE's own debugging tool and in HttpWatch Studio. I can't find the offending piece of code.

Are there any particular gotchas in IE that might trigger this warning?

Comment: I see it in Firefox 15 too, but only if I allow JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML source contains the line

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

which makes the browser try to fetch the URL https://secure.marietta.at/js/jquery.min.js.  However, this URL doesn't actually return any JavaScript code like you'd expect it to, but instead redirects to http://marietta.at/.

The fact that you later load another, working copy of jQuery from another URL hides this problem.

I would suggest either of the following solutions:

- Remove the broken jQuery URL from the page.
- Put an actual copy of jQuery at that URL so that it works (and remove the other, now redundant copy from the page).

I'd also suggest configuring your webserver so that it doesn't redirect from HTTPS to HTTP URLs, as that may violate the user's security expectations in general.

Comment: This is way better articulated than my answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Load your page in IE and view the source code. There are quite a few hard coded references to `http://en.marietta.at`. Seems like some of your jQuery calls might be loading that "insecure" content

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've figured it out - never load JQuery twice (esp. from with an invalid URI). I've mistakenly left it in the `<head>` and just above the `<body>` tag which resulted in the SSL error. Deleted one, which got rid of the error.